# Date picker with Today button

Tags: sapui5

I have a user input with `sap.m.DatePicker`. Is there a way to add a button to that calendar to select 'Today date'? I've seen some implementations with jQuery but I have an XML view.

I could add a button beside the input field, but I would like to have it in the calendar popup.

```xml
<DatePicker id="fromDate"
  change=".onChangeDate"
  value="{
    path: '/dateD',
    type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Date',
    formatOptions: {
      source: {
        pattern: 'dd/MM/yyyy'
      },
      pattern: 'dd/MM/yyyy'
    }
  }"
/>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Date picker: How to change the focus of calendar to today's date in UI5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51423273/date-picker-how-to-change-the-focus-of-calendar-to-todays-date-in-ui5)

Comment: _> Is there a way to add a button [...] to select 'Today date'?_ ... Yes since UI5 1.95: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70007023/5846045

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create a popover and include a sap.ui.unified.Calender in there with a button.

```js
var popover = new /*sap.m.*/Popover({
  showHeader: false,
  placement: "Bottom",
  content: [
    new /*sap.ui.unified.*/Calendar({
      months : 1,
      firstDayOfWeek : -1,
    }),
    new /*sap.m.*/Button({
      text: "Today date",
      type: "Transparent",
      press: this.onTodayFunction
    })
  ]
});

popover.openBy(oEvent.getSource());
```