# Date picker: How to change the focus of calendar to today's date in UI5?

Tags: date, input, sapui5

I'm facing an issue regarding [`sap.m.DatePicker`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/entity/sap.m.DatePicker). I want to see Today's Date in the calendar, when I click on the calendar Icon. But I'm not able to display. Below is my Code:

```xml
<DatePicker displayFormat="dd-MM-yyyy" valueFormat="yyyy-MM-dd" value="31-12-9999" navigate=".onNavigateDate"/>
```

[image: UI5 Date Picker 9999-12-31]

In the above screenshot, I'm getting date `31-12-9999` from the back-end. But if click on calendar icon, I should see today's date in the calendar. It is very difficult for the user to navigate to the current date.

I have tried using `setInitialFocusedDateValue` but it didn't work. Below is my JavaScript code for the `navigate` event.

```js
onNavigateDate: function(event) {
  var dateObject = event.getSource();
  dateObject.setModel(new JSONModel({ date: new Date() }));
  var m = dateObject.getModel();
  dateObject.setDateValue(m.getProperty("/date"));
  dateObject.setInitialFocusedDateValue(m.getProperty("/date"));
},
```

Can someone please help me to display today's date in the calendar if I click on the Calendar Icon?

Comment: Since UI5 1.95, the property `showCurrentDateButton` can be used. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70007023/5846045. The `navigate` handler is not needed for this case.

Answer (score 1):

I used the navigate event like this and it worked:

View:

```
<DatePicker
  id="DP1"
  placeholder="Enter Date ..."
  navigate="onNavigate"
  value="31-12-9999"
  class="sapUiSmallMarginBottom"/>
```

And in the controller:

```
onNavigate : function(oEvent) {
    oEvent.getSource().setValue(new Date())
}
```

The logic you are using on your *navigate* method does not seem to work. Probably because of your UI5 version. The *initialFocusedDateValue* property was only released on *version 1.46.0*. Also, keep in mind that the approach I did changes the value of the date picker, which means that once closed, it will have today's date as a value.

Answer (score 0):

by default it shows today's date
remove 31-12-9999 in here

```
<DatePicker displayFormat="dd-MM-yyyy" valueFormat="yyyy-MM-dd" editable="true" navigate="onclickDate" value="31-12-9999"/>
```

Comment: Hello @user3808826,
I need to keep "value" because, value is coming from backend service.. For your understanding i just given hardcoded value..

Comment: But why you want show a date from backend that is obviously no longer needed? What about setting a maxDate?

Comment: Actually i need to display the backend value first and then on click of calendar icon , I need to see todays date

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, you have to override a private function :-(

```
oDatePicker._openPopup = function() {
  var today = new Date();
  this.setValue(today.getFullYear() + '-' + (today.getMonth() +1) + '-' + today.getDate());      
  DatePicker.prototype._openPopup.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

http://jsbin.com/dotames/edit?html,js,output

because we cannot change value in the navigate event handle as it is too late (popover has already appeared)

Comment: Hello @user3808826,
This is also not behaving as expected, For the first time it is showing 9999 year calendar. But again if we click on the calendar icon then im getting current date

Answer (score 0):

> It is very difficult for the user to navigate to the current date.

Since UI5 1.95 [(commit `dd3aeaa`)](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/dd3aeaa06b4118d18a77e59d93262b0fdc3c7a35), controls displaying a calendar can set `showCurrentDateButton="true"` in order to display a `Today` icon in the navigation header area.

Here is a sample with `sap.m.DatePicker`:

```xml
<!-- No navigate handler needed -->
<DatePicker showCurrentDateButton="true"/>
```

```js
globalThis.onUI5Init = () => sap.ui.require([
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/XMLView"
], async XMLView => {
  const definition = document.getElementById("myxmlview").textContent;
  const view = await XMLView.create({ definition });
  view.placeAt("content");
});
```

```html
<script defer id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
  src="https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
  data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.core,sap.m,sap.ui.unified"
  data-sap-ui-oninit="onUI5Init"
  data-sap-ui-async="true"
  data-sap-ui-theme="sap_fiori_3"
  data-sap-ui-excludejquerycompat="true"
  data-sap-ui-compatversion="edge"
  data-sap-ui-xx-waitfortheme="init"
></script>
<script id="myxmlview" type="text/xml">
  <mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m" displayBlock="true">
    <App>
      <Page showHeader="false" class="sapUiResponsiveContentPadding">
        <DatePicker showCurrentDateButton="true" value="9999-12-31" width="12rem"/>
      </Page>
    </App>
  </mvc:View>
</script>
<body id="content" class="sapUiBody sapUiSizeCompact"></body>
```

[image: UI5 Calendar picker with "Today" button]

Once clicked, the calendar will navigate to and focus today's date.
Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Space</kbd>, or click the focused date to select today.