# Add "Today" button to controls that use calendar

Tags: datepicker, sapui5

In my UI5 app, I have a [`sap.m.DatePicker`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.DatePicker) object and I want to let user to pick today's date in one click.

I can add a button outside the `sap.m.DatePicker` but it looks ugly because I have about 15 `sap.m.DatePicker` objects on the same screen and it will be a poor UI/UX.

Is there any way to show a "Today" button in `sap.m.DatePicker`?

[image: DatePicker]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Date picker: How to change the focus of calendar to today's date in UI5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51423273/date-picker-how-to-change-the-focus-of-calendar-to-todays-date-in-ui5)

Answer (score 0):

yes, currently the easiest ways is as already suggested to extend the DatePicker. Anyways the DatePicker is an input with a button and calendar in a popover. So if you want to go the hard way you could assemble your own control.

Answer (score 0):

As of UI5 1.95 [(commit `dd3aeaa`)](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/dd3aeaa06b4118d18a77e59d93262b0fdc3c7a35), controls displaying a calendar can set `showCurrentDateButton` with `true` in order to display a *Today*-icon in the navigation header area.

Here is a sample with `sap.m.DatePicker`:

```js
globalThis.onUI5Init = () => sap.ui.require([
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/XMLView"
], async XMLView => (await XMLView.create({
  definition: document.getElementById("myxmlview").textContent,
  height: "100%",
})).placeAt("content"));
```

```html
<script defer id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
  src="https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
  data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.core,sap.m,sap.ui.unified"
  data-sap-ui-oninit="onUI5Init"
  data-sap-ui-async="true"
  data-sap-ui-theme="sap_fiori_3"
  data-sap-ui-excludejquerycompat="true"
  data-sap-ui-compatversion="edge"
  data-sap-ui-xx-waitfortheme="init"
></script>
<script id="myxmlview" type="text/xml">
  <mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m" displayBlock="true">
    <App>
      <Page showHeader="false" class="sapUiResponsiveContentPadding">
        <DatePicker showCurrentDateButton="true" value="1972-04-01" width="8rem"/>
      </Page>
    </App>
  </mvc:View>
</script>
<body id="content" class="sapUiBody sapUiSizeCompact"></body>
```

[image: UI5 Calendar picker with "Today" button]

Once clicked, the calendar will navigate to and focus today's date.
Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Space</kbd>, or click the focused date to select today.